# Angular 2 component relative path

Tags: angular, systemjs

My systemjs.config.js file maps the "app" to a "dist" folder. So if I try to reference my component html file relatively, I would get the following error:

Failed to load https://localhost:44337/dist/appComponent.html

Do I have to use gulp to copy the html files to the "dist" folder as well? What other options do I have? Absolute path works perfectly fine.

My system.config.js file:

```
(function (global) {
System.config({
    paths: {
        // paths serve as alias
        'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
        // our app is within the app folder
        app: 'dist',
        // angular bundles
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
```

App.component file:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "appComponent.html"
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use external templates, and relative paths in `templateUrl`, then yes you should copy the html files and place them in `dist` folder.

A task to move all `.html` files within `dev/` to your `dist/` folder

```
gulp.task('move-html',function(){
    return gulp.src('dev/**/*.html')
               .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

You have other options, such as using inline templates (writing the template within the component), or -- even better -- using [`gulp-inline-ng2-template` plugin](https://github.com/ludohenin/gulp-inline-ng2-template/blob/master/README.md) as a build task to import and inline the external templates for you.  This way, fetching the template will not require an additional http request.